# How to call an attr_accessor attribtue inside the class (but outside any methods)?

Tags: ruby, attributes

I'm using HTTParty for my class, and I want to use the default_params method. However, I also want to be able to set attributes when instantiation my class with initialize.

```
class MyClass
  include HTTParty

  attr_accessor :param1, :param2

  # This or @param1 doesn't work.
  default_params :param1 => self.param1, :param2 => self.param2

  def initialize(param1, param2)
    self.param1 = param1
    self.param2 = param2
  end
end
```

This way I can do

```
m = MyClass.new('hey', 'hello')
```

instead of

```
m = MyClass.new
m.param1 = 'hey'
m.param2 = 'hello'
```

But I'd like to use the attributes with default_params. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at the `initialize` method in [this example file](http://github.com/jnunemaker/httparty/blob/8da360fb4dbc54041a0e65e5b78a83ad408b7db4/examples/aaws.rb) from the Github repo. I haven't used HTTParty before, but this looks like what you're after.

Also, from your example, it looks like you're mixing up class methods and instance variables.

Answer (score 1):

Ruby has a syntax for that, in method declarations.

```
class MyClass
  attr_reader :param1, :param2
  def initialize(param1 = "default", param2 = 5) 
    @param1, @param2 = param1, param2
  end
end

MyClass.new.param2
# => 5
```

I have never used HTTParty, and I'm not sure what the `default_params` method does, so I dunno if this is what you're looking for.

Comment: Thanks, HTTParty and default_params don't really have to do with the question. I just need to know how I can access the attributes within the class, but outside of any methods.